# Hadoop: ClassNotFoundException - org.apache.hcatalog.rcfile.RCFileMapReduceOutputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm facing `ClassNotFoundException`, when I run my job for the class `org.apache.hcatalog.rcfile.RCFileMapReduceOutputFormat`.

I tried to pass the additional jar files with `-libjars`, still I am facing the same issue. Any suggestions will be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Below is the command I am using and exception I am facing!

```
hadoop jar MyJob.jar MyDriver -libjars hcatalog-core-0.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar inputDir OutputDir
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hcatalog/rcfile/RCFileMapReduceOutputFormat 
>           at com.cloudera.sa.omniture.mr.OmnitureToRCFileJob.run(OmnitureToRCFileJob.java:91) 
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70) 
>           at com.cloudera.sa.omniture.mr.OmnitureToRCFileJob.main(OmnitureToRCFileJob.java:131) 
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
>          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208) 
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hcatalog.rcfile.RCFileMapReduceOutputFormat** 
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) 
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) 
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) 
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) 
>           ... 8 more

I implemented `ToolRunner` as well, below is the code which confirms that!

```java
public class OmnitureToRCFileJob extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        OmnitureToRCFileJob processor = new OmnitureToRCFileJob();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(processor.getConf(), args).getRemainingArgs();

        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(processor.getConf(), processor, otherArgs));
    }

}
```

Comment: @Martin Prikryl

Hi Martin, how are you able to edit the question.. ?

is it like anyone can edit the questions we posted on StackOverFlow.. ? i am new t SOF.. can you tell me ?

Comment: There's "edit" link below tags (above comments). I believe anyone can edit his own posts.

Comment: yeah, everyone can edit his own posts. but how are you able to edit my post... ? that's confusing me!!

Comment: oh!
i dont know that... thank you Martin!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at hadoop command documentation, you can see that `-libjars` is a generic option. For parsing generic option, you got to override the `ToolRunner.run()` method in your driver class as follows :

```java
public class TestDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();

        # Job configuration details            
        # Job submission  

        return 0;
    }        
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new TestDriver(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

---

I'nk you are getting this exception from your driver code itself. Setting hcatalog-cor*.jar using -libjars option may not be available in client JVM(JVM in which driver code runs). Better you need to set this jar in HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable before executing the same using hadoop jar as follows

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:<PATH-TO-HCAT-LIB>/hcatalog-core-0.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar;
hadoop jar MyJob.jar MyDriver -libjars hcatalog-core-0.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar inputDir OutputDir
```

Comment: we implemented using the same way @sachinjose, see the below code for your reference! but still i am facing the issue!

public class OmnitureToRCFileJob extends Configured implements Tool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  OmnitureToRCFileJob processor = new OmnitureToRCFileJob();
  String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(processor.getConf(), args).getRemainingArgs();

  System.exit(ToolRunner.run(processor.getConf(), processor, otherArgs));
 }

}

Comment: Edited the question, to show the job code that confirms we implementing ToolRunner! 

please refer to the question to see my new changes!

Comment: Instead of passing otherArgs option, pass args directly to run() method.

Comment: Using GenericOptionsParser(processor.getConf(),args).getRemainingArgs();  option you are filtering out the generic option.

Comment: oops! could be @sachinjose

Comment: I will try removing that and will keep posted!

Comment: Also, my issue resolved when i created Runnable Jar file thru eclipse rather than creating Normal JAR file!!

Comment: i tried the same way what you suggested, but still the same exception prompting me @sachinjose

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running by giving full path of "hcatalog-core-0.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar" jar file in your below line.

```
hadoop jar MyJob.jar MyDriver -libjars hcatalog-core-0.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar inputDir OutputDir
```

or

Below configuration should also work for you

```
$ export LIBJARS= <fullpath>/hcatalog-core-0.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
$hadoop jar MyJob.jar MyDriver -libjars ${LIBJARS} inputDir OutputDir
```

Comment: my issue resolved when i created Runnable Jar file thru eclipse rather than creating Normal JAR file thru Eclipse!!

Answer (score 0):

Id had the same problem but found out the jar command doesn't accept the --libjars argument.
"Specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath. Applies only to job." --> [Hadoop Cli Generic Options](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options)

Instead you should use the env vars to add additional or replace jars.

export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="./lib/*"